# PUTing blocks into blob with java azure storage client

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload data to the same Block Blob in parallel, from multiple java processes.  The processes have no way of talking to each other, so they won't know when the last block has been uploaded.

I'd like to commit each block immediately after it has been uploaded by a process.  I thought I could use commitBlockList to do this, but its behavior seems to wipe out uncommitted blocks.  I tried synchronizing access to the blob via a lease, so that each process would acquire a lease on the blob and pull down the blocklist via downloadBlockList, and update the blocks each process has uploaded, but this still has unexpected behavior (blocks keep disappearing from the list).

Is there an operation in the java azure storage client that allows me to update the committed status of a SINGLE block in a Block Storage blob?  Alternatively, is there some parameter I can pass to uploadBlock that would make it immediately set the block's status to COMMITED after its finished uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my misunderstanding, from the docs:

"Any block commitment overwrites the blob’s existing properties and metadata, and discards all uncommitted blocks."

I was only acquiring the lease when I wanted to update the block list, not realizing that when I committed the block list, I would be destroying any uncommitted blocks not included in the list.  I didn't acquire the lease when writing my blocks, since that would destroy any parallelism I'd get from having multiple different processes uploading at the same time.

I'll just have to try something else.

Comment: Great, please mark it as an answer, it will help others.